# Broken Matplotlib installation, Conda Update Did not Work

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, anaconda

My installation of matplotlib seems to be broken.

I tried using conda update matplotlib, but the problem did not go away.  What else could I try?

The error I get when trying to import matplotlib.plt is given below

```
In [2]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-eff513f636fd> in <module>()
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

C:\Anaconda\envs\py33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in <module>()
     24 from matplotlib.cbook import dedent, silent_list, is_string_like, is_numlike
     25 from matplotlib import docstring
---> 26 from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
     27 from matplotlib.backend_bases import FigureCanvasBase
     28 from matplotlib.image import imread as _imread

C:\Anaconda\envs\py33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in <module>()
     22 from matplotlib import __version__ as _mpl_version
     23
---> 24 import matplotlib.artist as martist
     25 from matplotlib.artist import Artist, allow_rasterization
     26

C:\Anaconda\envs\py33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in <module>()
      5 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
      6 from matplotlib import docstring, rcParams
----> 7 from .transforms import Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox, \
      8                        TransformedPath, Transform
      9 from .path import Path

C:\Anaconda\envs\py33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py in <module>()
     33 import numpy as np
     34 from numpy import ma
---> 35 from matplotlib._path import (affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox,
     36     update_path_extents)
     37 from numpy.linalg import inv

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

In [3]:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `conda install -f matplotlib`

Answer (score 4):

Thanks asmeurer, your answer didn't quite work for me but pointed me in the right direction.

http://conda.pydata.org/docs/examples/install.html

```
conda install -f -n py33 matplotlib
conda install -f -n py33 pyparsing
conda install -f -n py33 numpy
```